# Android emulator closed because of an internal error

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

im using intellij idea on linux. I could not find anything on the internet about this error.

[image]

error reason https://paste.ee/p/HRvhW

Answer (score 7):

Possibly the hardware emulation is not working, so switch to software emulation.

[image]

Alternatively, if this dropdown is disabled edit:

C:\Users{`your_username`}.android\avd{`your_emulator`}.avd\config.ini

```
hw.gpu.enabled=no
hw.gpu.mode=off
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case, i attempted using gennymotion [ you may install it searching 
 genymotion on google] this could serve as alternative.

if gennymotion after installation returns this error message "the version of openGl supported by your graphics card is too old:Genymotion requires at least openGl 2.0 support. "

then know our challenge is  arising from not having required graphics driver

either you checkout this link [https://buffered.com/support/solve-opengl-error/]  on how to resolve it in steps.

or you download the graphics drivers using the links below

Here are the links to the 4 most prominent graphics card manufacturers in the world:

Intel: http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/detect.html
visit buffer site for other graphics card drivers

restart your systems after installation of the appropriate graphics driver and continue your project .

Answer (score 0):

Under C:\Users\userName.android\avd/Nexus_5_API_24.avd
Try to delete The files  have a ".lock" extension:
[image]

You don't need to touch the configuration files.
It should work.